# Applying scroll event listener to specific element with overflow-y

Tags: scroll, contextmenu, addeventlistener

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4eVy.png)  im making a to do list with a custom context menu and there is an element or better said a container in this app that contains the to do list tasks
when i click on of these tasks it display my custom context menu
however i want the scrolling of this list section to freez when context menu is in DOM
so i made this funcion and added an event listener to my list section

```
  await document.getElementById("list-section").addEventListener("scroll", (Event) => {
    FreezScroll(Event);
  });
```

```
function FreezScroll(Event) {
  if (DoesElementExist("context-menu")) Event.preventDefault();
}
```

note that the async and await works fine and DoesElementExist function is also working fine problem is the scroll event is not applied at all cause i tried to console log it in event listener block and it did not work while another event such as click works.

i tried different events to test if lines actually run and they do run i also tried to add event listener to both body tag and the specific element all result were failure